# String to number for sum

Tags: javascript, string

How do I convert the following string into a sum?

```
 var sums = [{sum:"0+0=0"},{sum:"1+0=1"}

 var str = sums[0].sum;

 var sum = 0;

 for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
     var n = parseInt(str[i])
     sum += n;//Help   
 }
```

The reason for this approach is that I am getting passed a string sum in an array. if it is not a string value then it cannot be passed without errors. I then need to evaluate the sum and return the answer.

Comment: your array is not valid

Comment: `sums[0]` is an `Object`. `str` would be `sums[0].sum`

Comment: What result do you want out of `parseInt(str[i])`? `"0+0=0"` is not a valid integer

Comment: can you mention what you want to do?

Comment: Are you trying to test whether the comparison is true?

Comment: I have updated to include .sum. parseInt(str[i]) would return    0,+,0,=,0 except that the "+" and "=" are not integers

Comment: This is for a bingo style math game. So the user will have to match the answer to the sum to a number tile on the bingo board. The sum has to be a string because otherwise javascript tries to do the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

`sums[0]` is an `Object`. `str` should be `sums[0].sum` and it will work.

But! Your current implementation will fail if numbers consist of more than 1 digit. Safer method would be splitting that string:

```
var sums = [{sum:"0+0=0"},{sum:"1+0=1"}]
var str = sums[0].sum;

// Detecting operator
var operator;
if ( str.indexOf( '+' ) ) operator = '+';
if ( str.indexOf( '-' ) ) operator = '-';
if ( str.indexOf( '*' ) ) operator = '*';
if ( str.indexOf( '/' ) ) operator = '/';

var chunks = str.split( operator );

var firstOperand = parseInt( chunks[0] );
var secondOperand = parseInt( chunks[1].split('=')[0] );

var result;
switch ( operator ) {
    case '+':
        result = firstOperand + secondOperand; break;
    case '-':
        result = firstOperand - secondOperand; break;
    case '*':
        result = firstOperand * secondOperand; break;
    case '/':
        result = firstOperand / secondOperand; break;
    default: break;
}

console.log( 'RESULT:', result );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this could get a bit bulky when I have to check for all operators "+ - / *". I am going to see if there is another workaround for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I am actually already splitting the sum up into a question and and answer and storing them in separate arrays ie "1+1" and "2". Your solution looks good, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the part of each string you want to sum is the part after the `=`:

```
var sum = 0;
var n = 0;
var result = "";

for(i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  n = str[i].sum.lastIndexOf('=');
  result = str[i].sum.substring(n + 1);

  sum += parseInt(result, 10); // don't forget to specify radix
}
```

That said, we really need more information to be able to help you.